# Почему не удаляются сессионные cookies при закрытии браузера?

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, браузер

Собственно суть в заголовке. Сессионные cookies ставятся как нужно:

```php
setcookie('name', 'var', 0, '/');
```

После закрытия браузера (пробовал на хроме, лисе), сессионные cookies продолжают жить. Почему они не удаляются после закрытия?
P.S. Фоновый режим в хроме выключен, после закрытия. Это первое о чём я подумал

Comment: Видимо время жизни этих куки не окончено

Comment: Для этого также нужно [установить параметр](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624378/make-sessions-last-until-browser-closes-php) session.cookie_lifetime в php.ini равном 0.

Comment: Это же сессионная кука, при закрытии браузера, браузер должен удалить её автоматом

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime равен 0, перепроверил